# Find Duplicate in Two Columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contain two column PropertyID and DistrictID
what I need is to find duplicate that match each PropertyID and DistrictID.
I mean each PropertyID and DistrictID repeated together.
please any help well be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to group by these columns:

```
SELECT  PropertyID, DistrictID
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY PropertyID, DistrictID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```